# Choosing capacitors for Buck Converter – How many Electrolytic, How many Ceramic?

Tags: capacitor, buck, decoupling-capacitor, component-selection

I am working on a high-power buck converter. This converter will be powering a purely resistive load *(it’s a literal resistor – a heating element)*.

However, **I am having some issues deciding how many electrolytic and how many ceramic capacitors to use.**

My switching frequency is 70kHz, I do not want the output ripple to accede 100mV, my maximum output voltage is 10.75V. Based on all this data, and knowing my load resistor **I can calculate the needed capacitance like so:**
[image: Calculations for Output Capacitance]

However there comes a problem, while yes 611.42uF may look like all I need, as we know electrolytic capacitors don’t work too well at high frequencies, so I need to add some ceramic capacitors. I have zero idea how to do this.

**So my question is:**

How do I split my needed output capacitance between electrolytic and ceramic capacitors. How much “ceramic capacitance” and “electrolytic capacitance” do I need, and how do I calculate it?

**Additionally,** how do I choose my input capacitance? All I know is that the Vin power supply is 24V and can provide 6A, but that’s all I know. I want to avoid creating lots of interference and ripple on the input side.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: Why are you concerned about ripple voltage on a heating element? What power is the feed in watts or kW? Is it 50 watts (no really high-power LOL). I'd use a synchronous buck converter made from MOSFETs.

Comment: Calculate the minimum required ESR to meet your ripple requirements. I’m with Andy, why are you concerned with ripple on a purely resistive load? You can simply pwm to control the power. No need for inductors etc.

Comment: I am concered about it, as the buck converter will have a trimpot to adjust the output voltage, with a large ripple it would be very difficult to do so.